# WPF Two way binding TreeView selected item - ComboBox text - ContainerViewModel property

Tags: wpf, mvvm, binding

**SOLVED**

I want ComboBox display category name (that is binded to int CategoryId via converter) when ProductDialogBox shows, but it doesnt update unless I manually choose some category from TreeView. The solution is to add  SelectedIndex="0" to ComboBox

By now the task is implemented like the following...

ProductDialogBox.xaml

```
<UserControl.Resources>
        <converter:CategoryIdConverter x:Key="categoryIdConverter" />

        <HierarchicalDataTemplate x:Key="NodeTemplate" ItemsSource="{Binding Path=Categories}">
            <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                <Image Source="/GSM.UI;component/Resources/Images/folder.png" Margin="1,1,3,1"/>
                <TextBlock x:Name="tb" Text="{Binding Path=Name}"/>
            </StackPanel>
        </HierarchicalDataTemplate>

        <DataTemplate x:Key="CategoryItemTemplateCollapsed">
            <TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=Name, Mode=OneWay}" 
                       DataContext="{Binding 
                           Path=DataContext.CategoryId,
                           RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type UserControl}},
                           Converter={StaticResource categoryIdConverter}}"/>
        </DataTemplate>

        <DataTemplate x:Key="CategoryItemTemplateExpanded">
            <TreeView ItemTemplate="{StaticResource NodeTemplate}" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" Margin="-4 0 -4 0" Foreground="#FF3C3C3C"
                      ItemsSource="{Binding Path=ItemsSource, RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type ComboBox}}}">
                <i:Interaction.Behaviors>
                    <b:BindableSelectedItemBehavior SelectedItem_="{Binding 
                        Path=DataContext.CategoryId, Mode=TwoWay, 
                        Converter={StaticResource categoryIdConverter}, 
                        RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type UserControl}}}" />
                </i:Interaction.Behaviors>
                <TreeView.ItemContainerStyle>
                    <Style TargetType="{x:Type TreeViewItem}">
                        <Setter Property="TreeViewItem.IsExpanded" Value="True"/>
                    </Style>
                </TreeView.ItemContainerStyle>
            </TreeView>
        </DataTemplate>
    </UserControl.Resources>

<ComboBox ItemsSource="{Binding Path=Categories}" SelectedIndex="0">
            <ComboBox.ItemTemplateSelector>
                <dt:CategoryTemplateSelector/>
            </ComboBox.ItemTemplateSelector>
        </ComboBox>
</UserControl>
```

ProductDialogViewModel.cs

```
    public ProductDialogViewModel(ProductViewModel product, bool update)
    {
        if(update)
            _product = updateProduct.Product;
        else
            _product = new Product();
    }

    public int CategoryId
    {
        get { return _product.CategoryId; }
        set
        {
            if (value.Equals(_product.CategoryId))
                return;

            _product.CategoryId = value;

            base.OnPropertyChanged("CategoryId");
         }
    }
```

**OLD QUESTION**
please advise how do I implement two way binding between `DialogBoxViewModel` and `TreeView` selected item through `ComboBox` displayed text?
A `TreeView` inside `ComboBox` displays collection of `CategoryViewModel` by `Name` property.
As the user selects a category in `TreeView`, a `ComboBox` text sets to category name and `DialogBoxViewModel` property `CategoryId` is set with `Id` of selected `CategoryVM`.
And backway, when `DialogBoxVM` property `CategoryId` is set, the `TreeView` selected item is set and the `ComboBox` text disaplys the corresponding category name

The problem partially solved by binding ComboBox selected value to the same property CategoryId, but it still does not displays anything when CategoryId is set.

```
// ViewModel
ProductDialogBoxViewModel.cs
    int CategoryId
    ObservableCollection<CategoryViewModel> Categories;

// View
ProductDialogBoxView.xaml

    <ComboBox SelectedValue="{Binding Path=CategoryId, Converter={StaticResource categoryIdNameConverter}, Mode=OneWay}"
              DisplayMemberPath="SelectedValue.Name">
      <ComboBoxItem>
         <TreeView ItemsSource={Binding Categories} ItemTemplate={<-- displays name of category -->}>
            <interaction:Interaction.Behaviors>
               <behavior:BindableSelectedItemBehavior 
                    SelectedItem_="{Binding Path=CategoryId, 
                                            Mode=TwoWay, 
                                            Converter={StaticResource categoryNameIdConverter}}" />
            </interaction:Interaction.Behaviors>
         </TreeView>
      <ComboBoxItem>
    </ComboBox>
```

Answer (score 0):

It is not possible to set the `SelectedItem` of `ComboBox` to item which is not in its ItemsSource. I had the similar requirement to show the treeview in Combobox. What I had to do is to create the new Combobox template where you have full control on the Text area and Combo popup. I then put my TreeView inside the Combobox popup in control template and bound the Text what I wanted to show on selection change of TreeView selected Item.

You can find the default combobox template here http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd334408%28v=vs.95%29.aspx and alter the part you want to.

You should have property `SelectedCategory` of type `CategoryViewModel` in `ProductDialogBoxViewModel`. Then you can directly bind SelectedItem of treeview to this property like `<TreeView ItemsSource={Binding Categories} SelectedItem = {Binding SelectedCategory}/>`

Whenever the selecteditem of treeview will change your SelectedCategory will change and vice-versa. Then you can bind this SelectedCategory Name to the text area of combobox in control template created.

Thanks

Comment: I appreciate so much for such fast reply! But theres no need to make SelectedCategory property because the value of SelectedItem is already a CategoryViewModel and I need only the category Id. The main propblem now is to display category Name in ComboBox text when CategoryId is set.

Comment: ahh,,read the question in haste.. pls see if the updated answer helps you

Comment: Thanks a lot, will try right now. By the way I think I got the main problem, it's how to convert CategoryViewModel to ComboBoxItem in converter so it could be displayed.

Comment: nit, though it is the best solution you suggested its difficult for me to implement that. By now the problem is solved in a very ugly way - via TemplateSelector, generating several binding exceprions in Output